# print line before string matchs in 2 successives lines

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I am using Linux and I need to print the line and the 2 successive lines that matches the same string on my file.

Here my example:
when 2 cars are driving on the same speed, i want to display the cars speed + the time

My file:

time: 10:15

car1 - speed 120

car2 - speed 120

time: 10:17

car16 - speed 89

car3 - speed 102

time: 10:26

car7 - speed 56

car15 - speed 56

time: 10:36

car9 - speed 115

car4 - speed 100

---

Thus, what I want as a result is:

time: 10:15

car1 - speed 120

car2 - speed 120

time: 10:26

car7 - speed 56

car15 - speed 56

---

Any help is really appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: What did you try exactly? Do you have a snippet?

Comment: Is this really what your input file looks like? Including bullets and horizontal lines? Probably not, but could you use a code block to format it exactly what your input does look like?

Comment: What shell are you using? bash? Since you list both Python and shell, would you be okay with, in principle, any language to solve your problem (e.g., Perl)?

Comment: bash is fine, then python if it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite easy with `sed` - we can use `N` (*append the next line of input into the pattern space*) to read the three lines, and a *backreference* `\1` to test for equality of speed:

```
sed -n '/time/N;/speed/N;/speed \(.*\)\n.*speed \1$/p'
```

Comment: Good point - I'll correct my answer.